# Datetime diff is not working in php

Tags: php, datetime, datediff

Here $current is the current timestamp and $added_time is the timestamp from when the item is added into the database. Both of them when echoed separately gives the correct o/p but when i try to calculate the difference between them using diff() function, the o/p i get is  "Y-m-d H:i:s".  What is happening?? I got no clue.

`$current = new DateTime();
 $diff = $current->diff($added_time);
echo $diff->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: it is.. otherwise it would show up as an error...

Answer (score 0):

The `diff()` method returns a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object holding the difference of the dates but the usual form `Y-m-d H:i:s` won't work as is; you need to prefix each format specifier with a percent symbol `%`

```
$current = new DateTime();
$diff = $current->diff($added_time);
echo $diff->format('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Comment: Hehe, that's nothing.